# Rails: application.css isn't compiled... but it is. Seriously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger, production-environment

**Update**: Problem solved, but the forum won't let me answer. See my comment below.

I have my assets precompiled. They show up in `public/assets` as expected. I also have `tmp/restart.txt` in my app (since I am using Passenger).

Yet I keep getting the same `ActionView::Template::Error (application.css isn't precompiled):` error in my production log file.

What's more? I completely removed the line that was calling for any css as a last ditch effort, and it is *still* giving the exact same error.

Before line removal:

```
Started GET "/" for 68.57.46.75 at 2013-07-24 22:35:14 +0000
Processing by EpisodesController#home as HTML
  Rendered episodes/_feature.html.erb (1.7ms)
  Rendered episodes/_feature.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered episodes/home.html.erb within layouts/application (4.1ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms

ActionView::Template::Error (application.css isn't precompiled):
    5:   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    6:   
    7:   <title>The Only Podcast on the Internet<%= @page_title ? ' - ' + @page_title : '' %></title>
    8:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
    9:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    10:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    11:   
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__3061238341936562138_19571120'
```

After line removal:

```
Started GET "/" for 68.57.46.75 at 2013-07-24 22:44:28 +0000
Processing by EpisodesController#home as HTML
  Rendered episodes/_feature.html.erb (1.8ms)
  Rendered episodes/_feature.html.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendered episodes/home.html.erb within layouts/application (4.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms

ActionView::Template::Error (application.css isn't precompiled):
    5:   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    6:   
    7:   
    8: 
    9: <meta property='og:image' content="<%= @page_image ? @page_image : $site_image %>" />
    10: <meta property='og:url' content="<%= request.protocol+request.host_with_port+request.fullpath %>" />
    11: <meta property='og:title' content="The Only Podcast on the Internet<%= @page_title ? ': ' + CGI::escapeHTML(@page_title) : '' %>" />
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__3061238341936562138_19571120'
```

I mean, *holy cow*. It's throwing up the same line as the source of the error and printing out an empty line there. Has anyone ever seen this?

Comment: Well, if that doesn't beat all.

Restarting the entire server fixed it. I cannot imagine why I'd need to shut the whole thing off all the way back to apache.

Jeez.